# What part of speech is "how" in "He did not know how he ought to behave"?

Tags: grammar

This is an example under the definition of *how* in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.

> He did not know how he ought to behave.

The dictionary lists *how* as an adverb. I understand this is because it modifies the verb *behave*, but I think it acts as a noun here.

Suppose we change *how* to *the way*.

> He did not know the way he ought to behave.

The meaning is still the same, but it looks like *the way* acts as a noun phrase here.

So, are both *how* and *the way* adverbs in this situation or are they nouns? If they are neither, what are they?

Answer (score 5):

It's a subordinating conjunction there.

[Merriam-Webster "how" conj. 1a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/how)
the way or manner in which
*asked how they could help*

The substitution you made does mean the same thing. It's a reduction of "the way *that* he ought to behave", which is a noun phrase modified by a subordinate clause.

Answer (score 3):

> *He did not know* [*how he ought to behave*].

"How" is an adverb here, but it doesn't modify the verb "know".

The bracketed element is an interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as **complement** of "know". The meaning is deontic, i.e. it doesn't mean whether he ought to behave but indirectly questions the manner in which he ought to behave.

Thus, the meaning is:

*"He did not know the answer to the question 'How ought he to behave?'"*

In your suggested alternant

*He did not know* [*the way he ought to behave*].

Again the bracketed element is an interrogative clause. It's not a question of not being familiar with the way he ought to behave, but of not knowing how to cognitively find the answer to the question "In what way ought he to behave?"